# How to remove OpenJDK and go back to regular JDK

Tags: macos, java

I mistakenly installed openJDK and I want to uninstall it and revert back to using regular JDK I had before, how do I do this? I can’t find anywhere how I can I uninstall it and go back to JDK.

Answer (score 8):

Oh, I just figured it out :)
Just go to your Library -> Java -> JavaVirtualMachines and there it will be the JDK and openJDK folders, just move the openJDK folder to the trash and it will go back to the original JDK, when you type in your terminal java -version you’ll see.